# Firebase Google cloud pubsub topic name convention

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

Is there any topic naming convention since i have been trying to name my topic `"googleDriveSync"` and it doesnt work for example call to `await pubsub.topic("googleDriveSync").exists();` throws an error but as soon as i add for example "myGoogleDriveSync" prefix to a topic name it works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Google Cloud Pub/Sub Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pubsub-basics#resource_names) on resource names:

> **Guidelines to name a topic, subscription, schema, or snapshot**
>
> A Pub/Sub resource name uniquely identifies a Pub/Sub resource, such as a topic, subscription, schema or snapshot. The resource name must fit the following format:
>
> `projects/project-identifier/collection/ID`
>
> - `project-identifier`: Must be the project ID or project number, available from the > Google Cloud console. For example, `my-cool-project` is a project ID. `123456789123` is a project number.
> - `collection`: Must be one of `topics`, `subscriptions`, `schemas`, or `snapshots`.
> - `ID`: Must conform to the following guidelines:
>
>   - Not begin with the string `goog`
>   - Start with a letter
>   - Contain between 3 and 255 characters
>   - Contain only the following characters: Letters `[A-Za-z]`, numbers `[0-9]`, dashes `-`, underscores `_`, periods `.`, tildes `~`, plus signs `+`, and percent signs `%`
>
> You can use the special characters in the preceding list in resource names without URL-encoding. However, you must ensure that any other special characters are properly encoded or decoded when you use them in URLs. For example, `mi-tópico` is an invalid ID. However, `mi-t%C3%B3pico` is valid. This format is important when you make REST calls.

As above, you inadvertently broke the "Not begin with the string `goog`" rule.